# Lock only one of two possible mutexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a multi threaded C++ program which simulates a car workshop. Basically a `car` is a thread here and a `station` is a resource. It works like this: Car enters a workshop and it has a list of stations (just ints), that it has to visit, to get repaired. There are 3 types of stations:

- 1x2 station - 1 station can repair 2 cars at once
- 1x1 station - 1 station can repair 1 car at once
- 2x1 station - there are 2 stations needed to get the job done

The last two types would be easy for me, cuz in the `1x1` type I just lock the mutex on `station` and other threads have to wait. On the `2x1` type I just go for `std::lock` on two stations to avoid deadlock etc.

The problem is with the first type. Lets imagine that repairing two cars at once means that one car is on the left hand side of the station and the other one on the right hand side (I will have to draw this situation with `ncurses` as well). So I thought about implementing a station for `1x2` type like this:

```
class station1x2 {
public:
    std::mutex r_mutex;
    std::mutex l_mutex;
}
```

So I would like to lock either the `r_mutex` or the `l_mutex`, so there are 4 possible scenarios:

- both of them are not locked, I lock whichever of them
- right one is locked, I lock the left one
- left one is locked, I lock the right one
- both of them are locked, I wait

The problem here is: Is there in C++ a mechanism to lock just one of given mutexes? (like I give some function my r_mutex and l_mutex and it chooses the not locked one and locks it for me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A mutex is not the correct synchronisation primitive here. This could be done with a *semaphore* (basically a 0-n primitive where a mutex is 0-1), but there is no semaphore in the standard library.

There is a condition variable, however, which you can use here. You will need:

- A condition variable to signal "there's free space in the station"
- A counter (or other means, such as two booleans) representing free spaces in the station
- A mutex to protect these

When entering the station, lock the mutex and see if there's any free space. If there is, occupy one, release the mutex, and get repairs. If both are full, wait on the condition variable (this will release the mutex).

When done with repairs, lock the mutex, mark your space as free, release the mutex and notify the condition variable (since there's free space now).

In code:

```
class station1x2 {
public:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    int freeSpaces;

    void enter() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mutex);
      cond.wait(l, [&]() { return freeSpaces > 0; }
      --freeSpaces;
    }

    void exit() {
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mutex);
        ++freeSpaces;
      }
      cond.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Two more questions: With that method, how can I know if the `right` spot is free or is it the `left` one? And then how do I communicate with that condition variable on another car (to check for free spaces?)

Comment: @Frynio You might maintain two booleans instead of the counter - as long as protected by the mutex, the data structure you use to hold the information is irrelevant for the synchronisation problem...

Comment: @Frynio In the simple code I've provided, just call `enter`. That will block until the condition (`freeSpaces > 0` in this case) is satisfied. You might want to read up on condition variables. Try starting here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: aren't semaphore only for ipc operations ? and i think recursive mutexes can remplace semaphores

Comment: @Tyker I didn't mean any particular implementation. On a conceptual level, a semaphore is a synchronisation primitive which allows N parallel runs and blocks a run if it would be the N+1st, until one current run finishes. A mutex is just a special case of semaphore with N=1. And how would a recursive mutex help for allowing <=2 threads in parallel?

Comment: ok for semaphores and i miss understood the probleme well and yeah recursive mutex can't help but it dosn't seem hard to do a semaphore from a mutex and atomics

Comment: @Tyker It is actually quite hard (if even possible) if you use neither a condition variable nor busy-wait.

Comment: Implement semaphore in terms of atomics.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would use the `try_lock` method. This method returns `true` (and locks the mutex) if the lock is possible, `false` otherwise (already locked mutex).

```
if (!r_mutex.try_lock() && !l_mutex.try_lock())
  std::cout << "All mutexes already locked" << std::endl;
```

Comment: This will turn into a busy-wait, as the thread would have to loop and keep `try`ing until it succeeds on one.

Comment: So if `try_lock()` returns true, it locks the mutex as well?

Comment: @Frynio Yes. Have you tried reading some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock)?